# RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation (...) fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Код:

```
import pandas as pd

calls_df, = pd.read_html('ссылка', header=0, parse_dates=["Call Date"])
print(calls_df)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lolo\PycharmProjects\untitled6\DDoS.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
    _win_os_check()
  File "C:\Users\lolo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
    raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\\Users\\lolo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information:
```

Ссылка после двоеточия ведет на: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: А пробовали читать по ссылке, которая идет после текста "See this issue for more information:"? Кстати, лучше добавить эту ссылку  вопрос.

Comment: @insolor Наверно я тупой и не пойму что там. Вы можете обьяснить и предложить шаги решения? Буду очень благодарен

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/y3dm3h86 - Ссылка. Сайт не дает вставить ее в вопрос

Comment: Ближе к низу по ссылке идут Solutions (решения). В качестве "обходного пути" (workaround) предлагают установить numpy версии 1.19.3: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html#reply-1241964

Comment: Точно тот же код, ошибка: raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера>

Comment: "Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, ..." означает что возникла какая-то сетевая проблема. Попробуйте позже еще раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По ссылке, приведенной в тексте ошибки, в качестве "обходного пути" (workaround) советуют ставить numpy версии 1.19.3:

[Источник](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html#reply-1241964)

> #### Workaround by mattip   03/11 06:37
>
> [Workaround]
>
> For all those at home following along and looking for a
> quick fix, NumPy has released a bugfix 1.19.3 to work around this
> issue. The bugfix broke something else on Linux, so we had to revert
> the fix in release 1.19.4, but you can still install the 1.19.3 via
>
> ```
> pip install numpy==1.19.3.
> ```
>
> Note this is only works around the way this bug crashes NumPy
> (technically, in OpenBLAS which is shipped with NumPy), and may not
> fix all your problems related to this bug, Microsoft’s help is needed
> to do that.

На данный момент самая свежая версия numpy - 1.19.4. Возможно позже будут исправления.

[mattip](https://github.com/mattip) - один из разработчиков numpy, см. [Contributors to numpy/numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/graphs/contributors).